# Endless Linked Loop When Deleting Elements From Linked List Recursively in c

Tags: c, loops, recursion, linked-list

I am studying for a test doing practice questions and cannot seem to get my linked list to work correctly with a function that recursively deletes elements from a linked list. Below is my full code, let me know if you see any way I can improve on my other methods as well. Thanks! :)

```
    /*
Q1: 
Try implementing the functions shown in class on your own: 
    check:  node creation 
    check:  insertion at the end of a linked list,
    check:  insertion at the head of a linked list, 
    check:  a list printing function.
Q2: 
    check: Write a recursive printList() function.
Q3:
    check: Write a recursive tailInsert() function.
Q4:
    check: Write a function that inserts nodes at the beginning of the linked list.
Q5:
    check: Write a recursive function that prints a linked list in reverse order. 
           The function signature is: void printReverse(node *head);
Q6:
    - Write an iterative destroyList() function that frees all the nodes in a linked list.
Q7:
    - Now implement destroyList() recursively.
Q8:
    - Write a function that deletes the nth element from a linked list. 
      If the linked list doesn't even have n nodes, don't delete any of them. 
      The function signature is: node *deleteNth(node *head, int n). 
     - Try implementing the function iteratively and recursively. 
     - (In terms of how to interpret n, you can start counting your nodes from zero or one; your choice.)
Q9:
    - Write a function that deletes every other element in a linked list. 
    - (Try writing it both ways: one where it starts deleting at the head of the list, 
    - and one where it starts deleting at the element just after the head of the list.)
    - Can you write this both iteratively and recursively?
Q10:
    - Write a function that deletes all even integers from a linked list.
Q11:
    - Write a function that takes a sorted linked list and an element to be inserted into that linked list,
      and inserts the element in sorted order. 
      The function signature is: node *insertSorted(node *head, int n);
Q12:
    - One of the problems with the first insertNode() function from today is that it 
      requires us to call it using head = insertNode(head, i). 
      That's a bit dangerous, because we could forget the "head =" part very easily. 
      Re-write the function so that it takes a pointer to head, 
      thereby allowing it to directly modify the contents of head without any need for a return value. 
      The function signature is: void insertNode(node **head, int data). 
      The function will be called using insertNode(&head, i).
*/

//come back to
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// Basic linked list node struct; contains 'data' and 'next' pointer.
// What happens if we type "node *next" instead of "struct node *next"?
typedef struct node
{
    // data field
    int data;

    // the next node in the list
    struct node *next;
} node;

// Allocate a new node. Initialize its fields. Return the pointer.
// We call this from our insertion functions.
node *createNode(int data)
{
    node *ptr = NULL;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("space could not be allocated\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    ptr->data = data;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    return ptr;
}

// Insert into the end of the linked list. Return the head of the linked list.
// (What is the order (Big-Oh) of this function?)
node *insertNode(node *head, int data)
{    
    node *temp;
    if (head == NULL)
        return createNode(data);

    for(temp = head; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next)
        ;
    temp->next = createNode(data);

    return head;
}

node *insertNodeFront(node *head, int data)
{
    node *temp;
    if(head == NULL)
        return createNode(data);

    temp = createNode(data);
    temp->next = head;

    return temp;
}   

// Simple function to print the contents of a linked list.
void printList(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty List\n");
        return;
    }

    for(; head != NULL; head = head->next)
        printf("%d ", head->data);

    printf("\n");
}

void printListRecursiveHelper(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return;

    printf("%d%c", head->data, (head->next == NULL) ? '\n' : ' ');
    printListRecursiveHelper(head->next);
}

void printListRecursive(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("empty list\n");
        return;
    }
    printListRecursiveHelper(head);
}
// Q3: - Write a recursive tailInsert() function.

node *tailInsert(node *head, int data)
{
    if(head->next == NULL)
    {
        node *temp;
        temp = createNode(data);
        temp->next = NULL;
        head->next = temp;
        return temp;
    }
    return tailInsert(head->next, data);
}   
//Q5: Write a recursive function that prints a linked list in reverse order. 
void printReverse(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return;

    printReverse(head->next);

    printf("%d ", head->data);
}

// Q6: - Write an iterative destroyList() function that frees all the nodes in a linked list.
// Got code from internet, memorize it
/* Function to delete the entire linked list */
void destroyList (struct node** head)
{
   struct node* current = *head;
   struct node* next;

   while (current != NULL) 
   {
       next = current->next;
       free(current);
       current = next;
   }


   *head = NULL;
}

//Q7:  - Now implement destroyList() recursively.
// Look up online, need to examine why it deson't work
node *destroyListRecursive(node *head)
{
    if ( head == NULL)
        return NULL;

    destroyListRecursive(head->next);

    free(head);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, r;

    // The head of our linked list. If we don't initialize it to NULL, our
    // insertNode() function might segfault.
    node *head = NULL;

    srand(time(NULL));

    // Populate the linked list with random integers. We are inserting into the
    // head of the list each time.
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("Inserting %d...\n", r = rand() % 20 + 1);
        head = insertNode(head, r);
    }
    head = insertNodeFront(head, 1);

    tailInsert(head, 5);

    // Print the linked list.
    printList(head);
    printf("\n");
    printReverse(head);
    printf("\n\n");

    // Print the linked list using our recursive function.
    printListRecursive(head);

    //destroyList(&head);
    head = destroyListRecursive(head);

    printList(head);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: `destroyListRecursive(head);

        printList(head);` : at `printList` : `head` already `free`'d `head`. Now, using `head` is UB.

Comment: @Janos whenever I run the program I get an endless loop around the destroy function.

Comment: Either make `destroyListRecursive` compatible with `destroyList` (i.e.) in `main`, do `destroyListRecursive(&head)`. Or, make it compatible with `head = destroyListRecursive(head)` and have the function return `NULL`. This is what BLUEPIXY is saying: that after the call `head` is pointing to an already deleted node (i.e. it should be `NULL` but it's non-null). It is the value of `head` in `main` (!!!) that is non-null, so `printList` will see an erroneous non-null value.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  I check to see if the head is NULL though, and if it is, it only prints out "empty list." I'm confused as to why it's an issue.

Comment: @CraigEstey I updated the code to the head = destroyListRecursive(head) and the function returns NULL, however, it crashes now. Did I implement what you were suggesting correctly?

Comment: Applying `free` to a pointer does not set the value of the pointer to `NULL`. After applying `free`, the pointer points to the memory block which has already been freed and can not be used.

Comment: Note: C does not support _methods_.

Comment: @starlight No, you missed a `return` statement at the bottom. See my answer below for a slightly cleaner way to write it. Also, your updated version would have been flagged as a compile error, particularly if you compiled with `-Wall` [which you should always do]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based upon my [and others] top comments, but this works [sorry to post the entire program for just the one line change in `main` and the rewrite of the function]:

```
/*
Q1:
Try implementing the functions shown in class on your own:
    check:  node creation
    check:  insertion at the end of a linked list,
    check:  insertion at the head of a linked list,
    check:  a list printing function.
Q2:
    check: Write a recursive printList() function.
Q3:
    check: Write a recursive tailInsert() function.
Q4:
    check: Write a function that inserts nodes at the beginning of the linked list.
Q5:
    check: Write a recursive function that prints a linked list in reverse order.
           The function signature is: void printReverse(node *head);
Q6:
    - Write an iterative destroyList() function that frees all the nodes in a linked list.
Q7:
    - Now implement destroyList() recursively.
Q8:
    - Write a function that deletes the nth element from a linked list.
      If the linked list doesn't even have n nodes, don't delete any of them.
      The function signature is: node *deleteNth(node *head, int n).
     - Try implementing the function iteratively and recursively.
     - (In terms of how to interpret n, you can start counting your nodes from zero or one; your choice.)
Q9:
    - Write a function that deletes every other element in a linked list.
    - (Try writing it both ways: one where it starts deleting at the head of the list,
    - and one where it starts deleting at the element just after the head of the list.)
    - Can you write this both iteratively and recursively?
Q10:
    - Write a function that deletes all even integers from a linked list.
Q11:
    - Write a function that takes a sorted linked list and an element to be inserted into that linked list,
      and inserts the element in sorted order.
      The function signature is: node *insertSorted(node *head, int n);
Q12:
    - One of the problems with the first insertNode() function from today is that it
      requires us to call it using head = insertNode(head, i).
      That's a bit dangerous, because we could forget the "head =" part very easily.
      Re-write the function so that it takes a pointer to head,
      thereby allowing it to directly modify the contents of head without any need for a return value.
      The function signature is: void insertNode(node **head, int data).
      The function will be called using insertNode(&head, i).
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

    // Basic linked list node struct; contains 'data' and 'next' pointer.
    // What happens if we type "node *next" instead of "struct node *next"?
typedef struct node {
    // data field
    int data;

    // the next node in the list
    struct node *next;
} node;

    // Allocate a new node. Initialize its fields. Return the pointer.
    // We call this from our insertion functions.
node *
createNode(int data)
{
    node *ptr = NULL;

    ptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("space could not be allocated\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    ptr->data = data;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    return ptr;
}

    // Insert into the end of the linked list. Return the head of the linked list.
    // (What is the order (Big-Oh) of this function?)
node *
insertNode(node * head, int data)
{
    node *temp;

    if (head == NULL)
        return createNode(data);

    for (temp = head; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next);
    temp->next = createNode(data);

    return head;
}

node *
insertNodeFront(node * head, int data)
{
    node *temp;

    if (head == NULL)
        return createNode(data);

    temp = createNode(data);
    temp->next = head;

    return temp;
}

    // Simple function to print the contents of a linked list.
void
printList(node * head)
{
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("Empty List\n");
        return;
    }

    for (; head != NULL; head = head->next)
        printf("%d ", head->data);

    printf("\n");
}

void
printListRecursiveHelper(node * head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return;

    printf("%d%c", head->data, (head->next == NULL) ? '\n' : ' ');
    printListRecursiveHelper(head->next);
}

void
printListRecursive(node * head)
{
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("empty list\n");
        return;
    }
    printListRecursiveHelper(head);
}

    // Q3: - Write a recursive tailInsert() function.

node *
tailInsert(node * head, int data)
{
    if (head->next == NULL) {
        node *temp;

        temp = createNode(data);
        temp->next = NULL;
        head->next = temp;
        return temp;
    }
    return tailInsert(head->next, data);
}

    // Q5: Write a recursive function that prints a linked list in reverse order.
void
printReverse(node * head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return;

    printReverse(head->next);

    printf("%d ", head->data);
}

    // Q6: - Write an iterative destroyList() function that frees all the nodes in a linked list.
    // Got code from internet, memorize it
    /* Function to delete the entire linked list */
void
destroyList(struct node **head)
{
    struct node *current = *head;
    struct node *next;

    while (current != NULL) {
        next = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }

    *head = NULL;
}

    // Q7: - Now implement destroyList() recursively.
    // Look up online, need to examine why it deson't work
node *
destroyListRecursive(node * head)
{

    if (head != NULL) {
        destroyListRecursive(head->next);
        free(head);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int i,
     r;

    // The head of our linked list. If we don't initialize it to NULL, our
    // insertNode() function might segfault.
    node *head = NULL;

    srand(time(NULL));

    // Populate the linked list with random integers. We are inserting into the
    // head of the list each time.
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Inserting %d...\n", r = rand() % 20 + 1);
        head = insertNode(head, r);
    }
    head = insertNodeFront(head, 1);

    tailInsert(head, 5);

    // Print the linked list.
    printList(head);
    printf("\n");
    printReverse(head);
    printf("\n\n");

    // Print the linked list using our recursive function.
    printListRecursive(head);

    // destroyList(&head);
    head = destroyListRecursive(head);

    printList(head);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess I was misunderstanding what everyone was trying to say when I was trying to implement the comments.